# UserProfiles - UserNotFoundExceptio

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service

Scenario:

- User X (AD user) has access to the sharepoint environment (full control permissions)
- Environment is load balanced
- The customer told me they use different domain notations (old = KL_CUSTOMERNAME, new CUSTOMERNAME.BE)
- Userprofile import has been done. User X is available.
- User X is available in the user information list

In a webcontrol on the homepage of our portal - I'm running the following code:

```
UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(SPServiceContext.GetContext(SPContext.Current.Site));
UserProfile profile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
```

I'm getting the following error when the user hit the page (webcontrol):

> (Er is een fout opgetreden bij het ophalen van het gebruikersprofiel.)
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserNotFoundException    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileCache.GetUserData(UserProfileManager
>   objManager, Nullable`1 recordId, Guid gAcct, String strAcct, Byte[]
>   bSid, String strEmail, Boolean doNotResolveToMasterAccount)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfile.RetrieveUser(String
>   strAcct, Guid gAcct, Byte[] bSid, Nullable`1 recordId, Boolean
>   doNotResolveToMasterAccount, Boolean loadFullProfile)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfile..ctor(UserProfileManager
>   objManager, String strAcct, Boolean doNotResolveToMasterAccount,
>   Boolean forceUserIsSelf, Boolean loadFullProfile)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManage...
>   65228af1-c6c3-4d84-a93f-752ff4c2f222 11/07/2011 16:47:23.07*  w3wp.exe
>   (0x3394)                           0x2A90  AZGroeninge Intranet
>   WebControls                       0000                Unexpected
>   ...r.GetUserProfile(String strAccountName, Boolean
>   doNotResolveToMasterAccount, Boolean loadFullProfile)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager.GetUserProfile(String
>   strAccountName, Boolean doNotResolveToMasterAccount)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Us

**Note: There are a couple of users for which the exception does not occur.**
Those users also have full control.

Has it something to do with the domain notations?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by performing an IISRESET after the full userprofile import.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get a UserProfile object for the current user? You can simply get it  via ProfileManager:

```
UserProfile profile = profileManger.GetUserProfile(true);
```

Comment: Yes,that's correct - but I use another constructor...
I does the same thing (normally)

Comment: @SvenGillis: It does the same thing if `User.Identity.Name` is exactly the same as the account name format expected by the `UserProfile` constructor. If you are looking for the current user, there is no reason not to use the default one.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Nemanjan. I investigated this a little further. When I use HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name for user X I notice it has the same domain notation as user Y. Nevertheless, I can retrieve the UserProfile object of user Y and not for user X. What am I missing here?